# Pymol: How to use a list index as input for a pymol function (align)?

Tags: list, indexing, alignment, pymol

I want to get the RMSD for each pair of poses generated by an autodock docking via the align function:

```
align pose1, pose2, cycles=0, transform=0
```

Instead of using the names of the poses as input, I want to access a list that contains all poses.
This list is successfully obtained via:

```
allobjects = cmd.get_object_list('all')
```

and

```
print(allobjects[x])
```

successfully prints the pose at position x in this list.

However, the following method did not work:

```
align allobjects[1], allobjects[2], cycles=0, transform=0
```

yields error: Invalid selection name "allobjects[1]"

What would be the correct way to feed the align function with the list indices?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can not pass values from python variables to the built-in functions of PyMOL. But there is almost always an equivalent python function that does the same and can receive regular pythonic arguments. In the case of `align` it would be `cmd.align()`.

The result of `cmd.align()` is not printed as nice as the `align` function, but instead a list of 7 elements is returned, being the first element the calculated RMSD. The meaning of the rest of the values can be found in the [source code of the function](https://github.com/schrodinger/pymol-open-source/blob/abd9579a97b9864c6a40ba7b91dd330ef64d14a5/layer4/Cmd.cpp#L1998-#L2004).

I also assume that you intent to calculate the RMSD for every possible pair of docked structures. For that purpose you have to use all the unique combinations of all structures and manually do a python loop over them. Be aware that the calculation time will increase exponentially with the number of structures you have.

```
allobjects = cmd.get_object_list('all')
from itertools import combinations
for pair in combinations(allobjects, 2): print(pair[0], pair[1], cmd.align(pair[0], pair[1], cycles=0, transform=0)[0])
```